# Sorting data from multiple .csv's into a single workbook

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a VBA script that reads through each CSV in a given folder, reads the data in and places it into a workbook. It then goes to the next .csv and appends that data to the very last row of the previous set of data.

I would instead like it to append the data from each .csv along the columns not the rows, however I am having some trouble wrapping my head around how to do this.  Here is the code:

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim inputValue As Variant

Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

inputValue = InputBox("Input File Path:")
FolderPath = inputValue

NRow = 1

FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*csv*")

Do While FileName <> ""

    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)


    SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName



    LastRow = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
             After:=WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Range("A1"), _
             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
             SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B" & LastRow)

    Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
    Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, SourceRange.Columns.Count)

    DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

    NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

    FileName = Dir()
Loop

SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: How about instead of identifying the last row, you identify the last column with something like `LastColumn = cells(1,16000).end(xltoleft).column` and then you could place the new file one column after that?

Answer (score 0):

This macro might help.

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger() Dim bookList As Workbook Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object Application.ScreenUpdating = False Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'change folder path of excel files here Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\guillermo.rojas\Documents\Desktop\Reports\EOD") Set filesObj = dirObj.Files For Each everyObj In filesObj Set bookList
= Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here 'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3 'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column 'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Application.CutCopyMode = False bookList.Close Next End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the LastColumn in the SummarySheet using the following code:

```
LastColumn = Workbk.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Then convert the LastColumn Number to letter using the following code or function:

```
LastColumnLetter = CovertToLetter(LastColumn)

Public Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Long) As String
   Dim iAlpha As Long
   Dim iRemainder As Long
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
End Function
```

Now Change DestRange like below

```
 DestRange = SummarySheet.Range(LastColumnLetter & 1)
```

Then increase the count of LastColumn as LastColumn = LastColumn + 1